# How to change the current point to the tip of an arrow without using \moveto?

Tags: pstricks

Consider the following code.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(3,1)
    \pscustom[linejoin=1,arrows=->]
    {
        \psline(0,-1)(1,0)
        \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{1}{2.25}{.25*sin(2*Pi*x/.25)}
        %\moveto(2.25,0)
        \psline(3,0)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The objective is to move the current point used by `\psline(3,0)` to the tip of the second arrow such that `\psline(3,0)` is parallel to the horizontal line.

How to move such a current point without using `\moveto(2.25,0)`? It seems the `\psplot` behaves abnormally, correct if I am wrong.

Comment: I notice that it looks "correct" if you get rid of the `arrows=->`, so apparently the routine that applies arrows to the end of a psplot line fails to put the current point back at the end of the line after it has drawn the arrowhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-1)(3,1)
    \pscustom[linejoin=1,arrows=->]
    {
        \psline(0,-1)(1,0)
        \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=100]{1}{2.25}{.25*sin(2*Pi*x/.25)}
        \psline(!SaveFinalState aload pop)(3,0)
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]